# How to create variable so activity know if image is fetched?

Tags: android, gallery

I have 4 methods that retreive URL's and then the Imageloader loads the images.

The images are set inside of a gallery view.

The problem is on smaller screens when the images are out of view they are reloaded when swipped back into view by the user.

HOw do i go about creating something to be tested and stop the images from being reloaded when the images are out of view?

Here is the code that loads the images.. The full class.

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


   myGames.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(n);

        }
    });
    gameNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }); 

    //Executing AsyncTask in background thread to get game images.
    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();

    myTask.execute();

}
 //Method to get images from text documents that will by updated every month.


public void getImages() throws IOException{


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");

              imageUrl = total.toString();
              Log.v("getImage1", "Retreived image");
            }
     }



            public void getImage2() throws IOException{

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImage2.txt");
                HttpResponse response;


                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                            total.append(line + "\n");

                          imageUrl2 = total.toString();
                          Log.v("getImage2", "Retreived image");
                        }
                }



                        public void getImage3() throws IOException{

                            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webimage3.txt");
                            HttpResponse response;


                                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                                    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                                    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                                    InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                                     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                                    String line;
                                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                                        total.append(line + "\n");

                                      imageUrl3 = total.toString();
                                      Log.v("getImage3", "Retreived image");
                                    }

                        }

                        public void getImage4() throws IOException{

                            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImage4.txt");
                            HttpResponse response;


                                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                                    HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                                    BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                                    InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                                    String line;
                                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                                        total.append(line + "\n");

                                      imageUrl4 = total.toString();


                            }
}

                        //ImageAdapter that gets the URL of the images and put them in a format to be set to gallery
            public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                /** The parent context */
                private Context myContext;public ImageAdapter() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }
                /** URL-Strings to some remote images. */

                public String[] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2,imageUrl3,imageUrl4};






                /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
                public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }





                /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
                public int getCount() { return this.myRemoteImages.length; }

                /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
                public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
                public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

                /** Returns a new ImageView to
                * be displayed, depending on
                * the position passed. */
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

                try {

                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();

                                conn.connect();

                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
                                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */

                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                bis.close();
                                is.close();
                                Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");

                                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
                        }

                /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                return i;
                }

                /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
                * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
                public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
                return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
                }
                } 





            //the important AsyncTask method. running the background thread to get the images and set them to the gallery.
                private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {try {
                            getImages();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 1 retreived");
                            getImage2();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 2 retreived");
                            getImage3();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 3 retreived");
                            getImage4();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 4 retreived");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("MainMenu retreive image", "Image Retreival failed");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override

                protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed){
                    ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                          .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));


                }

                        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try saving those fetched images to the cache, then for each image check if the image already exists in the cache so that it doesn't have to be downloaded again.

Comment: Could you you direct me in the direction for caching the images?

Comment: Does anyone know how I can accomplish csching the image, with the code I have above?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()